# Zip a folder with all its files and subfolders in it C# (DotNet 4.5)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, zip

I am trying to zip a folder with all its files and folders but its not working properly.
Here is the Folder i am trying to Zip it contains some files and a subfolder

[image]

and here is how i am doing it.

```
 System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(DestPath, ZipPath,System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel.Optimal,true);
```

but the result is this

[image]

It does not include xml file and the subfolder. Expected output should be like this

[image]

Is it possible to achieve without using an external library ?

Comment: It does not include the data.xml either? Are you sure your are pointing to the right source path? I just tried this locally on and it includes the files + sub directories.

Comment: yes the path is correct, double checked..

Comment: Can you provide that paths used? `DestPath` and `ZipPath`?